# Remove themes from Chrome

Tags: chrome, theme, web, appearance, mx-linux

I am using Chrome web browser on
MX Linux 19.2. I installed a theme from Chrome Web store. For removing an installed theme, you have to go to settings and click on appearance. There is an option to reset to default theme. But, in Linux version, this option is nowhere. It only shows a button to shift on classic or gtk+ theme. When the theme is changed to classic or gtk, the theme installed from store is simply disabled, but not removed. How can I remove it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no such implementation to remove installed theme or reset themes in Linux version of Chrome. They will actually not be storage intensive, but for removal, a reset of whole browser is needed by deleting it's directory from `~./config`.